# AWS Cloudsearch strange issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I uplaoded a JSON to cloudsearch with 1 field is 'text' type and searchable. It contains a word 'Residential'.

However if I use 'Residentia*', it shows me no search result. But using 'Residenti*' or 'Residential' is fine.

Who know about that? Thanks heaps!

Comment: Can you share your whole query? That sounds like it should work but I'm not sure what you're using as far as parser options, etc. Also take a look at the 'Searching for Prefixes' section if you haven't already http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-text.html

Comment: Hi alexrousses, no magic. I just manually upload a JSON string which has 'name' property in fields, and the name begins with 'Residentia ....'. Then I go to 'Run a Test Search' page and put search stuff as I mentioned above. Others are all default settings.

Comment: I was able to reproduce what you described. My only guess is that it has to do with stemming. Note that you can find "residentia" using fuzzy search by searching for "residentia~1" or by creating a suggester for that field. It sounds like you may be trying to do auto-complete, in which case you should be using a suggester anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into similar issues with Cloudsearch and I searched everywhere for the answer. I eventually came across a piece about "Algorithmic Stemming": https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/configuring-analysis-schemes.html.

The default stemming level for English text is "full". I created a custom analysis scheme with stemming set to "None" and applied that to most fields in document and it solved my problems.